# Get information from database and output to the view just one|first time

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I am trying to get out some information from the database, filter that information based on logged in user and then return the proper information to the view for built a menu based on user groups|roles|permissions.

This should only happen once and right after the user login in the application. For the menu I am using [this package](https://docs.spatie.be/menu/v1/introduction) and for the user/groups/permissions I'm using [Cartalyst Sentinel](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0).

I could use a `Middleware` but I think its purpose is not to get information from the DB and build some output or a `View Composers` but I don't want this to be executed all the time when layout or header is called which is almost all the time or all the time I would say or I can use a `Service Provider` I don't know to much about this latest.

So having this information: what would you do in this case? how would you built the menu and output to the `layout` or `section@header`?

Comment: why you dont get the  information from the database, filter it and do what ever you want, then  cache it and even if the page loades again, all of the above wont happen (untill changes to the current model happens and you can do this several ways)

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja that's what my question is about, what I don't know is how to caching that information, if you can write a small example will be perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple exemple

Lets suppose that you want to retrieve a user with his roles and cache the results

```
public function test() {
//getting authenticated user with roles
$userwithroles = Cache::remember('users-'.Auth::user()->id, 60, function() {
return User::with('roles')->where('id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
});
  return View('home')->with('$data',$userwithroles);
}
```

Now, the query will be executed only every one hour , you can look at the laravel docs to learn more tricks and cool other stuff

[**Caching in laravel**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/cache)

You can also check this [Video](https://laracasts.com/lessons/caching-essentials) (its laravel 4 but its almost the same)

I hope this might help